# Get babel automatically runs

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I perform the following evertimes to get babel watch the folder

```
babel src/app.js --out-file=public/scripts/app.js --presets=env,react --watch
```

anyway to configure it so that it runs by itself everytime?
I am developing ReactJS web apps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the command works, and you don't want to type the whole thing every time you start working.
If I'm correct, add it to your package.json.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel src/app.js --out-file=public/scripts/app.js --presets=env,react --watch"
  }
}
```

Save the file, open the command line, go to the project directory, and run `npm run start`.

Note: this will run the locally installed version of the babel-cli bin (/node_modules/.bin/babel).
If you type the same command in the command line (like before), it executes the globally installed babel-cli.